# How to set a breakpoint in standard/native JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger

Can I set a breakpoint on a standard JavaScript function? For example, can I pause the debugger every time [`context.beginPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) is called? Or every time that [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is called?

UPDATE: What I meant by *standard JavaScript function* is functions built-in into the JavaScript engines.

Comment: This maynot be useful but you can take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can do this by overriding the original functionality by performing the following two steps:

Make a copy(reference really) of the original function:

```
mylog = console.log;
```

Override the original with your copy inserting the `debugger` statement:

```
console.log = function(){
    debugger;
    mylog.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Now when called `console.log` will perform a breakpoint. (Note you'll have to handle different function arguments differently depending on the function be overriden)

Here is another example using an instance methods, for example `String.prototype.replace`:

```
let originalFunction = String.prototype.replace;
String.prototype.replace = function(...args) {
    debugger;
    return originalFunction.call(this, ...args);
}

console.log('foo bar baz'.replace('bar', 'BAR'));
```

Comment: Good point. I assume I can do the same with instance methods too, such as `String.replace()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the debugger statement?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant is how can I break in built-in JavaScript functions?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to set up a breakpoint and debug the code.

**1. Chrome dev-tools / Firebug:**

> Using Chrome developer tools or firebug to locate the line of
>   JavaScript, then set the breakpoint with the mouse. In chrome, you
>   should first open(ctrl+shirt+I) to open developer tools.
>
> Select the script tab or click on (ctrl+P) to open then desired file.
>
> Search the line on which you wanted to set a breakpoint and set a
>   breakpoint.
>
> Whenever you execute your code next time in a browser, the breakpoint
>   is fired. In watch section, you may see every expression, all
>   variables in scope, and the call stack too.

**2. Debugger**

> Using debugger statement, it fires every time and it helps when it
>   hard to find the execution of code.

```
debugger;
```

**3. Webstorm IDE / Visual Studio Code**

> Webstorm IDE/Visual Studio Code have the facility to debug a code from
>   IDE.

Javascript is a really flexible language and probably following the way to override existing javascript and debug method then please use following a way of debugging.

```
var fnSetAttribute = Element.prototype.setAttribute; 
Element.prototype.setAttribute = function(name, value) {
    if (name == 'clone') {
        debugger; /* break if script sets the 'clone' attribute */
    }
    fnSetAttribute.call(this,name,value); /* call original function to
    ensure those other attributes are set correctly */
};
```

For more reference please review https://alistapart.com/article/advanced-debugging-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome the convenience function [`window.debug()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities#debug-function) (only available from the console unless you assign it to a variable) allows setting breakpoints on builtin (or user-defined) functions:

```
debug(console.log)
console.log("Hello")
```

Shows the Sources pane and says

> Paused on debugged function

Remove the breakpoint with `undebug()`.